# How to add driver to ISO or bootable USB flash drive?

Tags: drivers, ethernet, iso-image, esxi

I'm trying to set up an ESXi (newest version) on my old Gaming Computer (HP Pavilion Gaming Desktop TG01-0050ng) (HP: 9CJ26EA#ABD).

How can I add a driver to my ISO or bootable USB flash drive?

If it is possible, I prefer to add the driver to the stick on Windows because I am most familiar with this OS.

I tried to boot from the bootable USB flash drive and I got the following error:

> "No Network Adapters No network adapters were detected. Either no network adapters are physically connected to the system, or a suitable driver could not be located. A third party driver may be required. Ensure that there is at least one network adapter physically connected to the system before attempting installation. If the problem persists, consult the VMware Knowledge Base."

I think that this is because I do not have the right network driver installed.

Comment: My answer aside, considering the mess with broadcom, running another virtualisation platform might be a good idea - proxmox is what I use, and unless your goal is to learn ESXi an open source option might go better

Answer (score 1):

The onboard card on your PC a Realtek RTL8118ASH, and in my experience ESX has had poor support for realtek

With *older* versions of ESXi you used to be able to use linux drivers on it, but I don't seem to think its possible now.

Since its a desktop your best bet is to find a seperate NIC that'll support ESXi from their HCL

Comment: BTW, there are USB WiFi and Ethernet adapters from ~US$10 and up, for each, available. Not sure which are compatible with ESXi, though.